# WPF styling custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control that I want to style:

It is just a class that inherits from TextBox and another Interface, the interface only adds an extra property.

How can I apply a style to this custom control so that when the read only property is set, the background turns gray?

---

```
public class DionysusTextBox : TextBox, IDionysusControl
  {

    public DionysusTextBox()
    {
      SetStyle();
    }

    #region IDionysusControl Members

    public bool KeepReadOnlyState
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(KeepReadOnlyStateProperty); }
      set { SetValue(KeepReadOnlyStateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeepReadOnlyStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("KeepReadOnlyState", typeof(bool), typeof(DionysusTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));

    #endregion

    #region Style

    Style styleListBoxItem = new Style(typeof(DionysusTextBox));
    Trigger triggerReadonly = new Trigger { Property = DionysusTextBox.IsReadOnlyProperty, Value = true };

    private void SetStyle()
    {
      triggerReadonly.Setters.Add(new Setter(DionysusTextBox.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
      this.Triggers.Add(triggerReadonly);
    }

    #endregion


  }
```

---

Above is the code for the entire class, the way I used the style seemed like the appropriate way but when I add this control to the designer I get the following error:

```
Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A `Trigger` can only be applied to a `Style`. In your case `styleListBoxItem` not `this`.

Comment: So simple, I changed it and don't receive a error anymore but the style does not work, any ideas?

Comment: I don't see that you apply the style.

Comment: @ChrisjanL Try setting this.Style = styleListBoxItem; Is there a reason you don't just define the style in XAML?

Comment: @AndyB, the control is only a .cs file. There is no xaml. I would've liked to put the style in my general resource dictiornary but it does not have access to the namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine dependency properties' default behavior, and in particular, you can define `PropertyChangedCallback`s:

```
public class DionysusTextBox : TextBox, IDionysusControl
{
    static DionysusTextBox()
    {   
        //For the IsReadOnly dependency property    
        IsReadOnlyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            //On the type DionysusTextBox
            typeof(DionysusTextBox), 
            //Redefine default behavior           
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                //Default value, can also omit this parameter
                null,
                //When IsReadOnly changed, this is executed 
                new PropertyChangedCallback(
                    (dpo, dpce) =>
                    {
                       //dpo hold the DionysusTextBox instance on which IsReachOnly changed
                       //dpce.NewValue hold the new value of IsReadOnly

                       //Run logic to set the background here, you are on the UI thread.

                       //Example of setting the BorderBrush from ARGB values:
                       var dioBox = dpo as DionysusTextBox;
                       //Should always be true, of course, it's just my OCD ;)
                       if (dioBox != null)                  
                       {
                          dioBox.BorderBrush = 
                              ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD") as Color?;
                       }
                    })));

        //For the BorderBrush property
        BorderBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            //On the type DionysusTextBox
            typeof(DionysusTextBox), 
            //Redefine default behavior           
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                //Default value
                ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD") as Color?));
    }


    public DionysusTextBox()
    {
      SetStyle();
    }
}
```

**Please be careful:** `UIPropertyMetadata` != `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`

Comment: This worked for me, just one question: I am setting the BackGroundProperty to Brushes.Gray but I'm getting the following error: 'System.Drawing.SolidBrush' is not a valid value for property 'Background'.. What should I set the background to?

Comment: @ChrisjanL Use `System.Windows.Media.Brushes` instead.

Comment: Last question! How would the following xaml be done like in your code: <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />

Comment: @ChrisjanL you'd do: `ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#DDDDDD") as Color;` and assign it to BorderBrush.

Comment: How do I assign BorderBrush in the static constructor?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question at all, it is not for when the IsReadOnlyProperty is changed. The border brush should always be set, only background is dependant on IsReadOnlyProperty.

Comment: @ChrisjanL I see, so you want to change the default value of BorderBrush? I'll edit again, maybe add it to your question.

Comment: i get the following error when adding my datagrid to a form: "Default value type does not match type of property 'BorderBrush'." @ "  BorderBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD") as Color?));"

Comment: @ChrisjanL You need to try until it works, my guess is it doesn't like the nullable Color.